# Contar y Mostrar registros en una tabla

Tags: php, mysql

Hola buen día tengo una duda sobre mis lineas de código,
estoy realizando conteo de registros

> $conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','123','com');

```
<?php
 $Tlax = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM entregable WHERE agen LIKE '%TLAXCALA%'");
 $result = mysqli_num_rows($Tlax);
printf("El resultado tiene %d filas.\n", $result);
mysqli_free_result($Tlax);                     
?>
```

Y me arroja **El resultado tiene 1 filas.** 
y en realidad son **539 registros**

Pueden decirme en donde esta mi error.

Comment: `SELECT COUNT(*)` te devolvera una fila

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema es que `mysqli_num_rows` te da el número de filas de la consulta. En una consulta `COUNT()` hay una sola fila, y el dato que se busca viene **en la columna del `SELECT`**, por tanto,  tienes que recuperar el valor de la columna para saber cuántas filas contó la consulta:

```
<?php
 # Damos el alias total al resultado de COUNT(*)
 $Tlax = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM entregable WHERE agen LIKE '%TLAXCALA%'");
 # Usamos mysqli_fetch_assoc (puede ser otro método si quieres)
 $result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Tlax);
 # Buscamos en $result  el valor que habrá en total, que es el alias que asignamos
 printf("El resultado tiene %d filas.\n", $result["total"]);
 mysqli_free_result($Tlax);                     
?>
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, siempre ayudandome a resolver mis dudas.

Comment: @user11149721 me alegro de que te haya servido. Saludos.